# sql oracle Union with null values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query on 2 views which when it unions

View X

```
A    B    C

2    3
```

View Y

```
A    B    C

     3    4
```

this is my query from the 2 views

```
select * from view X
UNION 
select * from view Y;
```

the result I had:

```
A    B    C

2    3   

     3    4
```

the result I wanted (the 2 overrides the null value in view Y @ attribute A):

```
A    B    C

2    3   

2    3    4
```

how can i obtained that ?

Comment: You misunderstand the union operator. It provides the set of distinct tuples from the queries being unioned together, hence the result you got. Please explain the logic you are using to produce the result set that you want. (What do you mean when you say that "the 2 overrides the null value in view Y @ attribute A"?)

Comment: Sorry my explaination was not detailed enough. the 2, i mean data stored in attribute X , number 2. sqlfiddle solved my query. Thanks to all anw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select nvl(A, lag(A) over (order by rownum)), B, C from (
  select A, B, C from X
  union 
  select A, B, C from Y
)
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/61f33/1)

Comment: thanks. it works like elixir. I'm a starter on oracle sql, but I have learnt something.

Answer (score 0):

here is one answer in oracle

```
select * from 
(select x from tbl1
union 
select x from tbl2) t1
,
(select y from tbl1
union 
select y from tbl2) t2
,
(select z from tbl1
union 
select z from tbl2) t3
where t1.x is not null
order by t1.x desc nulls first;
```